# "Who is" or "who was" the last person to do something?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage, sentence

I'm currently watching the US open at one of the commentators said "Andy Roddick was the last American male to win a grand slam". Is this correct, or should it be "he is the last American male to have won a grand slam"? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To win has no tense. We'd need *to have won* if we have to say "to have won a grand slam when he lost at shuffleboard." Setting the past against the more distant past.

Comment: Also: Is Andy dead or alive?

Comment: Andy is alive. . .and commenting on current events in tennis.

Comment: My intuition is that either is fine, although "is" maybe suggests it's more recent. I've a feeling this has been asked before, but good luck searching for it! (Certainly there have been similar questions about is/was.)